# accessing a foreign table's data from a view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

I am creating an inventory app in which a 'distribution' is the issuing of an item to an owner.

on my distribution.index page, I cannot determine how to show a distribution's owner's name (see below):

```
 <% @distribution.each do |distribution| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= distribution.id %></td>

    <td><%= (@owner[(distribution.owner_id)]).name %></td>

    <td><%= distribution.issued %></td>
    <td><%= distribution.returned %></td>

 </tr>
 <% end %>
```

error is : undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

I understand that distribution.owner_id must not be resolving into an integer that lets me find the correct owner.

controller:

```
def index
@distribution = Distribution.all

@item = Item.all

@owner = Owner.all
end
```

model:

```
 class Distribution < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :owner, :class_name => 'Owner', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
 has_one :item, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => 'item_id'
 has_one :type, :class_name => 'Type', :foreign_key => 'type_id'
 has_one :location, :class_name => 'Location', :foreign_key => 'location_id'
 end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :distribution, :class_name => 'Distribution', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
end
```

IS my schema set up incorrectly?:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141030135155) do

create_table "distributions", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "item_id"
t.integer  "type_id"
t.integer  "location_id"
t.integer  "owner_id"
t.date     "issued"
t.date     "returned"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end


create_table "owners", force: true do |t|
t.string   "first"
t.string   "last"
t.string   "dept"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have established all the relationship, try doing this:-

```
<td><%= distribution.owner.name %></td>
```

Comment: Im having the error:                             SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: owners.distribution_id: SELECT  "owners".* FROM "owners"  WHERE "owners"."distribution_id" = ? LIMIT 1       could it be my database is set up incorrectly? I looked at my schema and didnt see any reference ids...

Comment: Your schema is not correct. You need to add distribution_id column in owners table.

Comment: Also you can remove the additional attributes you have specified like classes and foreign key while declaring relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If a distribution can have or not an owner use this:

```
<td><%= distribution.owner.try(:name) %></td>
```

I advice change your index action, this way:

```
def index
  @ditributions = Distribution.includes(:owner, :item)
end
```

This work fine with pagination and optimizes db calls.

Model Distribution must `belongs_to :owner` and `belongs_to :item`, because the presence of fields owner_id and item_id. More information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one)